How to return a slice for an array created inside a function (in a clean Rust manner)
This is probably a question that has been asked many times, sorry about that.
I want to make a function that creates a byte array and returns a slice to it, and use only lifetimes.
I don't care how the byte array is created but it needs an initial size, and it will be mutated by a function that receives a unsized array. The function should return an unsized array (because in practice I do not know what is the size of the array at the start of the functions
fn create_new_byte_array(v :&[u8]) -> Result<&[u8], io::Error> {
    const N: usize = 1500;
    //let mut result: Vec<u8> = Vec::<_>::with_capacity(N);
    let mut result: [u8; N] = [0; N];
    // builder.write(&mut result.as_mut_slice(), v); // some byte transform
    return Ok(&result.as_slice());
}

How can this be done in a Rust manner? Any tips about other details are welcome for a noob.

You do it in a clean Rust matter (or any other matter) by not doing it.

return Box<[u8]> instead

Please explain why you want to do this and why returning an owned type doesn't work for you. You shouldn't be doing this without a VERY good reason. After all, the entire ownership system is designed specifically to prevent you from being able to do this.

If a function returns some data it has allocated, ownership needs to be transferred to the caller. References by definition do not allow this, so an owning type such as Box or Vec is needed.

The reason you can't generally return a slice referring to data created within a function like this is fundamental and there's no way around it, without allowing a memory leak.
A slice is just a view into some data stored in memory. It's a reference to an array. But where does the array itself live? If you create it with a Vec, then the array lives on the heap and you need to manage its ownership. When that Vec goes out of scope it will be dropped and its contents are then invalid.
If you create the array as a local variable in the function, then it's allocated on the stack, and it will cease to exist when the function returns.
If you want to return a slice referring to data created within the function, then you need to intentionally create a memory leak, but ensuring the referred-to data is never freed once you return the reference.
fn main() {
    let slice1 = make_slice(55);
    let slice2 = make_slice(66);
    println!("slice 1: {slice1:?}");
    println!("slice 2: {slice2:?}");
    // Note that slice1 and slice2 will never be freed since we called Vec::leak
}

fn make_slice(n: u8) -> &'static [u8] {
    let v = vec![n; 10];
    
    // The 'static lifetime means the referred-to data needs to be guaranteed to
    // live for the rest of the program's execution.
    v.leak()  // <-- data will NEVER be freed, we return a reference to this data
}


great reply it confirmed some of the things I was assuming, but does this mean that you can't have some kind of factory pattern without allocating to the heap (and forever)?
I was wondering if it was possible to relate the allocated memory with a lifetime, and return that?
